# Mootools hasClass issue in IE7 and IE8

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, mootools

I've got a site with contact panel that slides open on a click event. 
It's a MooTools script. It tested correctly in all browsers except IE7 and IE8. The Developer Toolkit in IE9 running IE8 and IE7 modes says it's because

```
SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'hasClass'
```

See the code below in action [here](http://jenkinsconsultancy.com.au)

```
$('contact-toggle').addEvent('click', function(event){
    event.stop();
     if(e.hasClass('active')) {
        closePanel();
       } else {
        openPanel(-380);
       }
});
```

Any thoughts on how to fix this?

UPDATE: Here's the whole of the MooTools script (updated as per comment below)...

```
window.addEvent('domready', function() {

var e = document.getElementById('info');
var contact_h = document.getElementById('contact-toggle-heading')   
var contact_i = document.getElementById('contact-toggle-icon');

function closePanel(){
      this.tween('margin-top',-50);
      this.removeClass('active');
      contact_i.setProperty('src', 'http://webiste.com.au/images/interface/arrow-up.png');
      contact_h.set('text','Contact');
      $$('.footer-header').removeClass('diminish');
}

function openPanel(panelHeight){
      e.tween('margin-top',panelHeight);
      e.addClass('active');
      contact_i.setProperty('src', 'http://website.com.au/images/interface/arrow-down.png');
      contact_h.set('text','Close');
      $$('.footer-header').addClass('diminish');
}

function timerPanel(){
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = (function(){ 
      closePanel();
    }).delay(5000);
}

$('contact-toggle').addEvent('click', function(event){
    event.stop();
     if(this.hasClass('active')) {
        closePanel();
       } else {
        openPanel(-380);
       }
});
}); //end script
```

Having swapped `e` for `this` worked - but the issue moved to the line `e.tween('margint-top...`. I've attempted to pass the event object along to the openPanel function, but no luck there yet.

Answer (score 3):

You should use $('info') instead of document.getElementById. In IE LTE 8 these elements are not extended by MooTools which causes the error. When you use the $ function the elements are extended and then document.getElementById will also work.

Answer (score 2):

What is `e`? Probably you should use `this`, because inside the event listener, `this === $('contact-toggle')`.

So use: `if (this.hasClass('active'))`

Comment: Heya @arian, using `this` worked... in as much as it moved the problem to a different part of the script. I might edit the original post to include the whole MooTools script...

Answer (score 1):

There's lots of problems here. Firstly you'll really benefit from keeping track of your Event variable. You define it as event, then change to e, then leave it out altogether.

start here,

```
//don't use document.getElementById it won't support methods like tween
var info = $('info')

$('contact-toggle').addEvent('click', function(e){
     e.stop();

     if(info.hasClass('active')) {
        closePanel();
     } else {
        //if -380 is a connstant, there's no need to pass it like this, define it in your function
        openPanel();
     }
});
```

Now let's deal with these

```
function closePanel(){
      info.tween('margin-top',-50);
      info.removeClass('active');
      contact_i.setProperty('src', 'http://webiste.com.au/images/interface/arrow-up.png');
      contact_h.set('text','Contact');
      $$('.footer-header').removeClass('diminish');
}

function openPanel(){
      var panelHeight = -380; //this should be probably be a computed property

      info.tween('margin-top',panelHeight);
      info.addClass('active');
      contact_i.setProperty('src', 'http://website.com.au/images/interface/arrow-down.png');
      contact_h.set('text','Close');
      $$('.footer-header').addClass('diminish');
}
```

That should get you started. Look into using Mootools Classes too, they're great and really make things a lot easier.

Comment: neither of these is the cause here, though.

Comment: maybe not, but I'd be willing to bet that the problem with e.tween... is that e is never defined. In my version of the script it is (although tween is called on 'element' instead)

Comment: how much are you willing to bet? `var e = document.getElementById('info');` in the upper scope is inherited. e is not an extended element.

Comment: global scope, you strike again! But yeah, n3on's answer would address that problem. I'll edit to fix.